# Помогите пожалуйста с кодом, выводит значения на 1 меньше

Tags: python

Итак, вот сама задача:
"Пифагоровы тройки"
Напишите программу, которая находит тройки натуральных чисел a,b,c таких, что `a⩽b⩽c⩽n` и `a^2+b^2=c^2`.

Заметьте, что таким образом, вы найдёте все прямоугольные треугольники с целочисленными сторонами.

Формат входных данных
В первой строке содержится целое число n (1⩽n⩽10^3).

Формат результата
Выведите тройки a,b,c в лексикографическом порядке.

Пример:
Входные Данные:

```
15
```

Результат:

```
3 4 5
5 12 13
6 8 10
9 12 15
```

Вот мой код:

```
def pif_triples(n):
    tmp = [k * k for k in range(1, n + 1)]
    res = []
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            q = tmp[i] + tmp[j]
            if q in tmp:
                k = tmp.index(q)
                res.append((i, j, k + 1))
    return res


n = int(input())
for a in pif_triples(n):
    print(*a)
```

и при вводе 15, он выводит

```
2 3 5
4 11 13
5 7 10
8 11 15
```

Что делать, как поменять?

Comment: Что делать - учиться элементарные методам отладки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индексация списков начинается с нуля. Чтобы получить соответствие чисел и их квадратов не по индексам, а по значениям, можно использовать словарь. Ваш код с минимальными изменениями, делающими его рабочим. Только сами изменённые строки:

```
tmp = {k: k * k for k in range(1, n + 1)} # словарь вместо списка
...
            if q in tmp.values(): # ищем в значениях словаря
                k = int(q**0.5)   # лучше создать обратный словарь, но и так сойдёт
                res.append((i, j, k)) # никаких k+1 не нужно
```

Вывод:

```
15
3 4 5
5 12 13
6 8 10
9 12 15
```

Этот код не оптимален, я просто указал на вашу ошибку и показал, как её можно исправить.

В принципе ваш код чинится ещё короче, но я считаю, что сам подход с обращением по индексам не очень хороший, тут нужно думать о соответствии. Словарь надёжнее. А так то можно починить и так:

```
tmp = [k * k for k in range(n + 1)] # начинаем список с нуля
...
               res.append((i, j, k)) # зачем там было +1 я так и не понял
```

Comment: `int(q**0.5)` -> `math.isqrt(q)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да по-хорошему там вообще без вычисления корня можно )

Answer (score 1):

В других ответах уже поправили ошибки, не буду повторятся.

Если говорить о поиске пифагоровых троек по определению, то такой код решает задачу:

```
def pythagorean_triples(n):
    squares = {i ** 2: i for i in range(1, n)}

    for a in range(1, n):
        for b in range(a, n):
            c = squares.get(a ** 2 + b ** 2)
            if c is not None:
                yield a, b, c


for a in pythagorean_triples(int(input()) + 1):
    print(*a)
```

Код перебирает ***a ≤ b < n*** и проверяет что ***a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>*** попадает в список полных квадратов чисел меньших ***n***:

> ```
> $ time echo 1000 | python pythagorean-triples.py
> 3 4 5
> 5 12 13
> 6 8 10
> 7 24 25
> 8 15 17
> ...
> 640 672 928
> 650 720 970
> 660 693 957
> 680 714 986
> 696 697 985
>
> real  0m0.326s
> user  0m0.320s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Это работает. Но можно обойтись без перебора и поиска.

Примитивные пифагоровы тройки образуют троичное [дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA).

Примитивная тройка - три натуральных числа со свойствами

***a < b < c***, ***НОД(a, b, c) = 1***, ***a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> = c<sup>2</sup>***.

Из каждой примитивной тройки можно построить три новые примитивные тройки:

- ***a' = a - 2b + 2c***, ***b' = 2a - b + 2c***, ***c' = 2a - 2b + 3c***;
- ***a' = 2a + b + 2c***, ***b' = a + 2b + 2c***, ***c' = 2a + 2b + 3c***;
- ***a' = -2a + b + 2c***, ***b' = -a + 2b + 2c***, ***c' = -2a + 2b + 3c***.

Для новых троек ***c' > c***. Что позволяет останавливать обход дерева если оказалось ***c ≥ n***.

Все примитивные тройки образуют дерево с корнем ***3, 4, 5***.

Кроме примитивных троек надо будет выдать и не примитивные. Этим занят отдельный цикл. Генератор выдаёт тройки без определённого порядка, в конце будет нужна сортировка. Этот метод работает намного быстрее:

```
def pythagorean_triples(n):

    def rec(a, b, c):
        assert a < b < c
        if c < n:
            yield from (
                (i * a, i * b, i * c)
                for i in range(1, (n + c - 1) // c)
            )
            yield from rec(
                    a - 2 * b + 2 * c,
                2 * a -     b + 2 * c,
                2 * a - 2 * b + 3 * c
            )
            yield from rec(
                2 * a +     b + 2 * c,
                    a + 2 * b + 2 * c,
                2 * a + 2 * b + 3 * c
            )
            yield from rec(
                -2 * a +     b + 2 * c,
                -    a + 2 * b + 2 * c,
                -2 * a + 2 * b + 3 * c
            )

    return sorted(rec(3, 4, 5))


for a in pythagorean_triples(int(input()) + 1):
    print(*a)
```

> ```
> $ time echo 1000 | python pythagorean-triples.py
> 3 4 5
> 5 12 13
> 6 8 10
> 7 24 25
> 8 15 17
> ...
> 640 672 928
> 650 720 970
> 660 693 957
> 680 714 986
> 696 697 985
>
> real  0m0.072s
> user  0m0.064s
> sys   0m0.008s
> ```

За шесть секунд находятся все 1980642 троек до миллиона:

> ```
> $ time echo 1000000 | python pythagorean-triples.py | wc -l
> 1980642
>
> real  0m6.068s
> user  0m5.984s
> sys   0m0.168s
> ```